# Jmeter how to modify a variable in BeanShell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have the following situation with jmeter:
I have two thread groups and I want to use a variable extracted from a response from the first one into the second thread.
What I am doing:

1. the variable is extracted with JSON/YAML Path Extractor and then it is set as a property with BeanShell Assertion `${__setProperty(id, ${id})};`
2. Then in the second thread group I have a BeanShell PreProcessor where I am trying to modify the value with the following script

```
    String ids2 = props.get("id");
    String ids3 = vars.put(${__intSum(2,-4)});
    String ids = vars.put(ids,"${__intSum(${ids2},${ids3})}");
```

As result I am getting an exception in jmeter

```
ava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.IntSum.execute(IntSum.java:66) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:91) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.unwrapProperty(TestBeanHelper.java:129) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.prepare(TestBeanHelper.java:84) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:202) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:382) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
```

The goal is to reduce the variable with 2 and then to transfer it to another variable which I will use only in the second thread group

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You may consider following 1. Convert the string `ids2 ` into a number before adding 2. vars.put() need to have two parameters `key,value`. Both key and value should be Strings 3. `ids` should be within quotes 4. Use JSR223 Components with Groovy

Answer (score 0):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
2. Your approach might work for 1 thread but if you will have > 1 thread the property will be overwritten, if you want each thread (virtual user) to have its own value you should add the current thread number as the prefix or postfix for the property. The relevant function is [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) or if you prefer scripting you can call [`ctx.getThreadNum()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum--)
3. In the vast majority of cases [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) is easier to use